# loading a SWC asset by variable name

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, swc

I am trying to load assets from an SWC into a SWF at compile time, in as3. I'm getting the information about which assets to load from a JSON file. I can do so statically, but when I try to define the names dynamically, I'm running into problems.

So for example I can do this:

```
onemech[+ tmpObj.id] = new mech3 as MovieClip;
```

And it loads the asset named mech3. But what I would like to be able to do is something like

```
var mechtype:String = "mech" + mechtypenumber;    
onemech[+ tmpObj.id] = new mechtype as MovieClip;
```

Obviously, that doesn't work.

I looked around a bit and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412375/flash-as3-attach-swc-symbol-based-on-xml-element) here, which seems to be angling toward what I need, but I can't figure out how to apply what's said there to my specific situation.

For the record, I have control over both the JSON format and the naming schema within the asset SWC, if there's an easier solution there.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need something like this:

```
var s:Class = getDefinitionByName("Symbol") as Class;
addChild(new s());
```

Comment: So, this makes sense to me, and thank you for the clarification. I actually figured this part out, and it turns out I was asking the wrong question. The real problem I'm having is not understanding the process by which classes are instantiated from the swc file. I need to do a bit more research and try to reform this into an actual question, but are there any resources you can point me toward wrt that?  Thank you for answering the question I asked, even if it turned out to not be the question I needed to ask :)